# Check if string is in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to see if a particular string exists in a particular column within my dataframe.

I'm getting the error

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
> a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

```
import pandas as pd

BabyDataSet = [('Bob', 968), ('Jessica', 155), ('Mary', 77), ('John', 578), ('Mel', 973)]

a = pd.DataFrame(data=BabyDataSet, columns=['Names', 'Births'])

if a['Names'].str.contains('Mel'):
    print ("Mel is there")
```

Answer (score 183, accepted):

`a['Names'].str.contains('Mel')` will return an indicator vector of boolean values of size `len(BabyDataSet)`

Therefore, you can use

```
mel_count=a['Names'].str.contains('Mel').sum()
if mel_count>0:
    print ("There are {m} Mels".format(m=mel_count))
```

Or `any()`, if you don't care how many records match your query

```
if a['Names'].str.contains('Mel').any():
    print ("Mel is there")
```

Comment: If there's NaN values in `a['Names']`, use the `na` parameter of the `contains()` function. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html

Comment: Gotcha number 2: `str.contains('Mel')` matches on every substring of every row in dataframe column.  So `ABCMelABC` == `Mel`.

Comment: This answer is incorrect & misleading since you are checking if 'Mel' is contained in any of the string in the column e.g. 'hi Mel' in the column will also evaluate to true whereas an exact match of the string is required

Answer (score 42):

You should use `any()`

```
In [98]: a['Names'].str.contains('Mel').any()
Out[98]: True

In [99]: if a['Names'].str.contains('Mel').any():
   ....:     print("Mel is there")
   ....:
Mel is there
```

`a['Names'].str.contains('Mel')` gives you a series of bool values

```
In [100]: a['Names'].str.contains('Mel')
Out[100]:
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
Name: Names, dtype: bool
```

Comment: If i want to check whether either of the words exist a['Names'].str.contains("Mel|word_1|word_2") works. Can you please suggest something for 'and' condition. I want to check if all the words in my list exist in each row of dataframe

Answer (score 23):

OP meant to find out whether the string 'Mel' *exists* in a particular column, not *contained* in any string in the column.  Therefore the use of *contains* is not needed, and is not efficient.

A simple equals-to is enough:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"names": ["Melvin", "Mel", "Me", "Mel", "A.Mel"]})

mel_count = (df['names'] == 'Mel').sum() 
print("There are {num} instances of 'Mel'. ".format(num=mel_count)) 
 
mel_exists = (df['names'] == 'Mel').any() 
print("'Mel' exists in the dataframe.".format(num=mel_exists)) 

mel_exists2 = 'Mel' in df['names'].values 
print("'Mel' is in the dataframe: " + str(mel_exists2))
```

Prints:

```
There are 2 instances of 'Mel'. 
'Mel' exists in the dataframe.
'Mel' is in the dataframe: True
```

Comment: a similar solution:
(a['Names'].eq('Mel')).any()

Comment: This is the most accurate answer

Comment: Why does one have to go down to numpy simply to check if a string is contained in a Series of strings? (like 'Mel' in df['names'].values). Seems contra-productive. I would expect `'Mel' in df['names']` to work?

Answer (score 10):

I bumped into the same problem, I used:

```
if "Mel" in a["Names"].values:
    print("Yep")
```

But this solution may be slower since internally pandas create a list from a Series.

Comment: it works for multiple string in that columns, thanks

Answer (score 4):

If there is any chance that you will need to search for empty strings,

```
    a['Names'].str.contains('')
```

will NOT work, as it will always return True.

Instead, use

```
    if '' in a["Names"].values
```

to accurately reflect whether or not a string is in a Series, including the edge case of searching for an empty string.

Answer (score 4):

For case-insensitive search.

```
a['Names'].str.lower().str.contains('mel').any()
```

Answer (score 2):

Pandas seem to be recommending `df.to_numpy since` the other methods still raise a `FutureWarning`: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy

So, an alternative that would work int this case is:

```py
b=a['Names']
c = b.to_numpy().tolist()
if 'Mel' in c:
     print("Mel is in the dataframe column Names")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
s = 'string'

df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.findall(s, flags = re.IGNORECASE)

#or
df['Name'] = df[df['Name'].isin(['string1', 'string2'])]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

(data_frame.col_name=='str_name_to_check').sum()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the results then you can use this:

```
a['result'] = a['Names'].apply(lambda x : ','.join([item for item in str(x).split() if item.lower() in ['mel', 'etc']]))
```

Answer (score -1):

You should check the value of your line of code like adding checking length of it.

```
if(len(a['Names'].str.contains('Mel'))>0):
    print("Name Present")
```