# how to get range of index of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

What is the most efficient way to get the range of indices for which the corresponding column content satisfy a condition .. like rows starting with  tag and ending with "body" tag.

for e.g  the data frame looks like this

[image]

I want to get the row index  1-3

Can anyone suggest the most pythonic way to achieve this?

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame([['This is also a interesting topic',2],['<body> the valley of flowers ...',1],['found in the hilly terrain',5],
             ['we must preserve it </body>',6]],columns=['description','count'])

print(df.head())
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code or data. [“Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Comment: @wwii I keep that in mind. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What condition are you looking to satisfy?

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame([['This is also a interesting topic',2],['<body> the valley of flowers ...',1],['found in the hilly terrain',5],
             ['we must preserve it </body>',6]],columns=['description','count'])
print(df)
print(len(df[df['count'] != 2].index))
```

Here, `df['count'] != 2` subsets the df, and `len(df.index)` returns the length of the index.

Updated; note that I used `str.contains()`, rather than explicitly looking for starting or ending strings.

```
df2 = df[(df.description.str.contains('<body>') | (df.description.str.contains('</body>')))]
print(df2)
print(len(df2.index))
```

help from: [Check if string is in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30944577/check-if-string-is-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to add the condition in the question.. well the condition that I am looking is  rows starting and ending with <body>, </body> tag

Answer (score 0):

You can also find the index of start and end row then add the rows in between them to get all contents in between

```
start_index = df[df['description'].str.contains("<body>")==True].index[0]
end_index = df[df['description'].str.contains("</body>")==True].index[0]

print(df["description"][start_index:end_index+1].sum())
```