# Pandas Dataframe subset not working as expected

Tags: python, string, pandas, if-statement, subset

This seemingly simple exercise is throwing me off my tracks, I'm sure it's something simple skipping my eye.

Let's say I have a dataframe

```
 datas = pd.DataFrame({'age':[10,20,30],
                          'name':['John','Mark','Lisa']})
```

I now want to subset the dataframe by the name 'Mark' so I did:

```
    if (datas['name']=='Mark').any():
        datas.loc[datas['name'] == 'Mark']
    else:
        print('no')
```

Expected result is

```
age name
20  Mark
```

but I get the original dataframe back again, please assist.

I've looked at several posts but none seems to help.

Posts example I looked at: [Check if string is in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30944577/check-if-string-is-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need assign back to original `DataFrame` if need overwrite original `DataFrame` by subset:

```
datas = datas.loc[datas['name'] == 'Mark']
```

Or assign to new variable, e.g. `df1`:

```
df1 = datas.loc[datas['name'] == 'Mark']
```

Next if data pare processing and assign putput to new variable like `df1`is necessary use [`DataFrame.copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) for prevent `SettingWithCopyWarning`:

```
df1 = datas.loc[datas['name'] == 'Mark'].copy()
```

If you modify values in `df1` later you will find that the modifications do not propagate back to the original data (`df`), and that Pandas does warning.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to print the subset? Right now your code doesn't change anything.

```py
if (datas['name']=='Mark').any():
    print( datas.loc[datas['name'] == 'Mark'] )
else:
    print('no')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your dataset even in one line:

```
datas = datas[datas['name']=='Mark']
```