# Replace entire cell with string if it consists a particular string

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I have a Dataframe `df`:

```
name     rank
A    captain, general, soldier
B    general, foo, major
C    foo
D    captain, major
E    foo, foo, foo
```

I want to check if any cell in the column `rank` consists of `foo` and if it does **replace the whole cell** with `foo`.

Expected output:

```
name     rank
A    captain, general, soldier
B    foo
C    foo
D    captain, major
E    foo
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if string is in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30944577/check-if-string-is-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional Replace Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21608228/conditional-replace-pandas)

Answer (score 1):

You can `apply` a lambda function to the column :

```
df["rank"] = df["rank"].apply(lambda x: "foo" if "foo" in x.split(", ") else x)
```

Splitting on the separator allows to check for words. For example, the world "foobar" wouldn't trigger the transformation on its row.

Edit: Thanks to BeRT2me for suggesting to split by ', '.

Answer (score 1):

```
df['rank'].replace('.*foo.*', 'foo', regex=True, inplace=True)
# OR
df['rank'].mask(df['rank'].str.contains('foo'), 'foo', inplace=True)
# OR
df.loc[df['rank'].str.contains('foo'), 'rank'] = 'foo'
```

Output:

```
  name                       rank
0    A  captain, general, soldier
1    B                        foo
2    C                        foo
3    D             captain, major
4    E                        foo
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mask = df['rank'].str.contains('foo')
df.loc[mask, 'rank'] = 'foo'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if df['rank'].str.contains('foo').any():
 df['rank']='foo'
```

Comment: wouldn't that just replace the whole series with `foo`